# Como trabalhar com Ajax com JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function getJson() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            async : false
        });

        $.getJSON(baseURL + "/ObterCursos",
                function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            items.push({
                                "Codigo" : val.Codigo,
                                "Nome" : val.Nome
                            });
                });
        });
}
```

Na primeira vez que ela é chamada, demora um pouco para trazer os resultados, mas nas vezes seguintes ela funciona rapidamente. Mas descobri que se eu compilar esse código em um projeto `Cordova`, mesmo sendo chamada novamente e existindo valores diferentes sendo retornados da solicitação, esse método não atualiza os resultados. O que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser um problema relacionado com cache. Para testar/resolver podes fazer 2 coisas:

1- desliga o cache do Jquery. Coloca `cache: false,` no setup do ajax.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async : false,
    cache: false
});
```

2- coloca um timestamp na url para a url ser sempre diferente e forçar o browser a fazer o pedido sem cache.  Por exemplo:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
$.getJSON(baseURL + "/ObterCursos?ts=" + timestamp, function(data) {
```